# Why do games lag in Unity and not in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

`Ubuntu 12.04`: All games lag in `Unity`, but in `Unity 2D` games don't lag. Does anyone have a solution that it don't lag in normal unity?

```
processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8500 @ 3.16GHz × 2

memory: 3,9 GiB

graphics: GeForce GTX 460


Ubuntu 12.04 32-Bit fresh installed (before 11.10 32-Bit all have worked)
driver: NVIDIAs accelerated Video card driver (Version current-updates)

games: neverball, beep, volley brawl (offline)
```

`Under 11.10` all Games worked fine

Comment: Can you please edit your question to describe what your specs are, like processor speed or RAM? Besides, could you name the games which are you talking about? Do you play online or offline?

Comment: Competing with Unity for GPU resources might have something to do with it, but if so that's just one piece of the puzzle as the problem *didn't* happen for you on Unity in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you don't have proper drivers for your GeForce GTX 460 or you graphics card is not fully supported, so try to download them from GeForce website.

You can do some performance testing by installing glxgears (`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`).

See [Bad 3D Performance in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136054/bad-3d-performance-in-ubuntu-12-04)

See [this article to check your performance issues](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxPerformance/3Dperformance/3Dperformance_glxgears.htm)

You could also try switching your desktop environment (Unity) to a different one, like KDE or something by installing one of these alternative desktops

- `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
- `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`
- `sudo apt-get install kde-full`

Comment: Especially when installing large metapackages (like those that provide desktop environments), if you do it from the command line, it's a good idea to run `sudo apt-get update` first, so that you're getting the current recommended versions, rather than downloading old versions and then downloading newer versions later when you update.