# Low graphic performance with Mobility Radeon HD 4200 under Unity3D

Tags: unity, ati, performance

On my *Lenovo Edge 11"* I got *Ubuntu 12.04* installed. It runs with a *ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 (RS880M)* and the additional ATI drivers are correctly installed ("lshw -c video" gives me a correct response).

Thing is, under Unity3D my system is very slow. What do you think, is my graphic adapter too slow or is there any other problem? I already reduced effects using *CompizConfig* but that had no effect at all.

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you don't have proper drivers or you graphics card is not fully supported, so try to download them from ATI website.

You can do some performance testing by installing glxgears `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Or via the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

---

See similar topic (with the answers):

- [Bad 3D Performance in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136054/bad-3d-performance-in-ubuntu-12-04)

See following articles to check your performance issues:

- http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxPerformance/3Dperformance/3Dperformance_glxgears.htm

In my opinion, you should change your desktop to different one, like KDE or something by installing one of following alternative desktops:

- [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

  [image: Install via the software center]
- [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

  [image: Install via the software center]
- `sudo apt-get install kde-full`

  [image: Install via the software center]