# Low Framerate ATI Radeon HD 5670

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx

When I try fgl_glxgears, I'm getting a framerate of under 60 fps. All the forum posts and askubuntu posts I've read suggest that I should be seeing at least triple digits. When this machine had windows installed it was pretty decent running games like WoW at around 60-70fps.

$glxinfo

```
name of display: :0.0 display: :0  screen: 0 
direct rendering: Yes 
server glx 
vendor string: ATI server 
glx version string: 1.4
```

$fglrxinfo

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0 
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5670 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

$dpkg -l fglrx* | grep ^ii | awk ' { print $2 }'

```
fglrx
fglrx-amdcccle
fglrx-dev
```

I followed this procedure from another post, and saw some increase in performance.

1. sudo apt-get purge fglrx fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle
2. sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates

fgl_glxgears = 80-90 fps
glxgears = ~300 fps

Which is more than double previous rates, but I see people with excess of 1000 fps. Am I missing something?

### Update 2

I've tried installing the proprietary drivers by following the instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI with much the same result.

### Update 1

Interestingly, If I minimize glxgears while it's running, I see a fps rate of 5300+.

### Bonus points:

Also, there's this annoying little habit of games to somehow shut off my second monitor. Is there a way to stop that? (when full screen is enabled)

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest drivers following this procedure: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers ?

Comment: That's the same procedure as the link I provided in update 2, so yes, I have.

Comment: Comment bump!!!